# MariaDB table missing but I can't recreate it

Tags: mariadb, foreign-keys, database-indexes

Something went wrong during a structure synchronization between two databases.

One of our production databases now is missing a key table 'customers' (which just about every other table has foreign keys to)

I'm trying to recreate the table from last night's backup (I don't want to restore the entire db - just recreate this table as the data in it does not change that much and I don't want to lose the transactional data from today)

The hassle seems to be that all the foreign key data for this table still exists in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE and I am getting 121 and 150 errors when I try run the CREATE TABLE query.

I've manually deleted all FK to the missing table and I am still getting errno 150 when trying to recreate the table. Any ideas where else there might be lost references to this table that is stopping me creating it again?

Comment: You could *recreate* the db. That is, script it to SQL and then run it. This will clean it. This would also allow you to find  other references to `customers`.

Comment: Answers belong in answer posts, not question posts. I rolled back your inappropriate edit of an answer into the question post. You can copy & paste the raw text of your answer from the pre-rollback version by clicking on 'edited' & then the version. [answer] [ask] Please don't insert "EDIT"s/"UPDATE"s, just make your post the best presentation as of edit time. Product/tool versions belong in tags. [Help] PS Debug questions require a [mre]. Research is expected, basic questions & error message questions are faqs.

Answer (score 0):

This was eventually resolved by multiple consultations of the `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` query.

The missing table had various indexes - example on the customer name there was an index "customer_name_idx". The CREATE TABLE query asked for this index to be created. The show engine innodb status return was "could not create table because index customer_name_idx already exists."

There was no reference to this index, to any primary key or to the table itself in any of the meta-data tables - I checked

```
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_SYS_INDEXES
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_SCHEMA
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS -INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE
```

so I could not explain why this error was being thrown.

My guess, after the fact, is that MySQL is holding a cached copy of the information_schema meta data in memory and was consulting that, and maybe that only gets refreshed if you restart MySQL?

The solution was to give the indexes new names as a short term fix, and to rename them during our next scheduled downtime.

Once these were made, the table was created and the backup data could be reinstated.